# Phalcon: how to define constant which is visible on all Controller and Model

Tags: model, controller, constants, visible, phalcon

Anyone know how to define constants which is visible on all Controller and Model of application.

For example, where I can defines these constants:

```
define('APP_CONST_ACTIVE', 1);
define('APP_CONST_INACTIVE', 0);
define('APP_CONST_ENABLE', 1);
define('APP_CONST_DISABLE', 0);
```

Or should I define these constants in which class:

```
class WhichClass
{
    const APP_CONST_ACTIVE = 1;
    const APP_CONST_INACTIVE = 0;
    const APP_CONST_ENABLE = 1;
    const APP_CONST_DISABLE = 0;
}
```

I would like these constants are visible on all Controller and Model of my application.

---

Let me clarify my question.

I want to define these constants only 1 time, and I would like to access them in all Controller, Model, and View.

For example in CakePHP, if in app/Config/core.php, I defined followings:

```
Configure::write('ENABLE', 1);
```

Then in all CakePHP Controller, Model, and View, I can access these constants in this way:

```
Configure::read('ENABLE');
```

So my question is: where should I define these variables which is visible on whole application with Phalcon? Maybe in `bootstrap` file, but how to do that?

Many thanks.

Comment: Let me clarify my question.

I want to define these constants only 1 time, and I would like to access them in all Controller, Model, and View.

For example in CakePHP, if in app/Config/core.php, I defined followings:

    Configure::write('ENABLE.ENABLE', 1);
    Configure::write('ENABLE.DISABLE', 0);

Then in all CakePHP Controller, Model, and View, I can access these constants in this way:

    Configure::read('ENABLE.ENABLE');

So my question is: where should I define these variables which is visible on whole application with Phalcon?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

look at: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/cli.html
I define the bootstrap constant and I can take everywhere.
It works for me.
sorry for my bad English !!

bootstrap:

```
define('VERSION', '1.0.0');
[...]
application = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application($di);
echo $application->handle()->getContent();
```

Controller:

```
namespace App\Controllers\xxx;
class IndexController extends ControllerBase
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
     echo VERSION;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either method. IMHO, a better approach is to use them inside the class vs globally defined constants. It feels more natural with the rest of OOP code, you can logically separate constants into classes and namespaces, most IDEs will treat them better, so it would be easier to refactor / maintain the code later.

Stating the obvious, but if you use the class with constants and your question is how to use them in any controller:

```
namespace My/Name/Space/Controller;

use My/Name/Space/WhichClass;

class AnyClass 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        echo WhichClass:: APP_CONST_ACTIVE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **ControllerBase.php** inside ***Controllers*** directory
then inside of file use an initialize function to insert anything for global usage in all controllers

the code should be same as this:

```
class ControllerBase extends Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
    protected function initialize()
    {
       define('WORLD_SAVIOR', 313);
    }
}
```

then in other controllers extend the base:

```
class IndexController extends CnotrollerBase
{
  //echo WORLD_SAVIOR;
}
```

now you can use defined constant in each file in the project